# Text File Code Puzzle.Replacing characters

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I have been trying to complete a task, which gives the user a list of symbolized words and they have to solve the symbols to reveal the word. I've created a menu with three options: `Add, Delete, Check`.

I'm stuck on the `Add` part.The user sees `A))85`, the correct word is `AFFIX`.

So, when on the menu screen I'll replace `)` with `F`. This prints the line `AFF85`, which it should.

When the user is prompted to change another symbol/letter pairing they will change `8` with `I`, however the program will print `A))IX` not `AFFI5`, which it should.

My code for that part is this:

```
def menu():

 print ("------------------Menu------------------")
    print ("1.Add Pairing")
    print ("2.Delete Pairing")
    print ("3.Check")
    sleep(3)
    menuchoice=input("1 or 2 or 3:")
    if menuchoice=="1":
        addpairing()
    elif menuchoice=="2":
        deletepairing()
    elif menuchoice=="3":
        check()


def addpairing():
    global words
    newcontentsA = (words)
    newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('#','A')
    newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('*', 'M')
    newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('%', 'N')

    addpairing1=input("Enter a SYMBOL you would like to replace::")
    addpairing2=input("What LETTER will you replace it with::")
    newcontentsA=newcontentsA.replace(addpairing1,addpairing2)
    print(newcontentsA)
    sleep(3)
    print("Lets get back to the menu")
    menu()
```

Is there something I've missed or is my code wrong?

Comment: Where is `words` coming from? Maybe you should have a `temp_words` variable that stores the current state for the user doing the replacements? You are replacing the symbols in `newcontentsA` and storing the result there, but each time you call `addpairing` that variable gets replaced with `words`.

Comment: Another point -- although it's not the cause of your problem -- you're doing unnecessary recursion. addpairing() should return to menu(), and menu() should loop (with an option to exit). Instead, menu() calls addpairing(), which calls menu() again, which calls addpairing() again, etc. Nothing ever returns, and you just keep building up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You do not store the pairings that the user adds. You apply them and then print.
Meanwhile, you never modify the content of the global `words` variable.
Because of this, everytime you call `addpairing` you start from scratch.

I would suggest that you maintain a data-structure with all the pairings that are active.
You should use a `dict` (dictionary) for that.
Then when you print (and you might want to put that in a separate function) you first take words, put it in a temporary variable, then loop over the (key, value) pairs in the dictionary
and make your substitution like you already do, then print.

Also I'd suggest not using a global variable. I think this is what confused you, and it isn't a great construct for most use cases.